# Error: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I am a new programmer and I recently started making websites with flask. I am recently started making a mini YouTube with flask, but I have this issue with the database. When i make a new entry to the database it gives me this error: "Error: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given"

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, session, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ChannelDB(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    subs = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    num_of_videos = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

channel_fields = {
    "id": fields.Integer,
    "name": fields.String,
    "email": fields.String,
    "password": fields.String,
    "subs": fields.Integer,
    "num_of_videos": fields.Integer
}

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/create_acc", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def create_acc():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["nm"]

        check = ChannelDB.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

        if not check:
            email = request.form["em"]
            psw = request.form["ps"]

            channel = ChannelDB(0, name, email, psw, 0, 0)
            db.session.add(channel)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for("user"))
        else:
            abort(409, message="Video alredy exists")

if __name__=="__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This here is the code in my .py file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="/create_acc", method="post">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="nm"></p>
        <p>Email: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="em"></p>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="ps"></p>
        <p>Press this button when you fill the spots above</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This here is my login.html file is case it helps.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see if you have defined an def __init__ anywhere in your code . so maybe that is why it is taking a default 1 positional argument for the __init__(constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` requires *keyword arguments* instead of *positional arguments*. The difference is to prefix the values with the name of the field:

```py
channel = ChannelDB(id=0, name=name, email=email, password=psw, subs=0, num_of_videos=0)
```

---

Also a few tips:

- Don't use `first()` to check if a record exists, but use [`.exists()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists). It results in faster queries, Python doesn't have to parse the response into a `Channel` object, and you'll use less bandwidth, because the database doesn't send the record, it only sends True or False;
- Look into [column `default`s](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#scalar-defaults). Of course a new channel always has 0 subscribers, if you add a default, you don't have to specify that. Same for number of videos;
- A primary key normally never needs to be specified, because the database just counts from 1 for you. Explicitly specifying it can actually lead to problems, because most databases keep a separate running counter that is then out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

Your channelDB class is missing an **init**() method.
I have modified it below

```
class ChannelDB(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, id, name, email, password, subs, num_of_videos): #newly added line
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
        password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
        subs = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        num_of_videos = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChannelDB` has no init method to take all the arguments you pass in.

Either create an init method or set the values directly as attributes on the instance. eg `channel.name = "some name"` and so on.

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a default `__init__` method

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. While your solution is preferable, afair mine works, too.

Comment: Actually, for my last project I created a custom init in order to handle default values.

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be useful. I also use them when I want to do some data transformation beforehand